# How to assign strings and variables to a variable

Tags: python, string, variables, object

```
class Bird:
    def __init__(self):
        self.noise = "chirping"
        self.beak = "closed"
        self.wings = "closed"
    def __str__(self):
        msg = "The bird is ", self.noise "its beak is ", 
               self.beak "its wings are ", self.wings
        return msg
mybird = Bird()
print(mybird)
```

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, but I need this to print my Bird object.

This is the error python gave me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:/000- Python-Coding/Practice/ bird object program.py", line 10, in <module>

   print(mybird)

TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)
```

Answer (score 3):

As the error message stated:

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)
```

You were building a tuple instead of string, so I suggest to use string formatting, like so:

```
msg = "The bird is {}, its beak is {}, its wings are {}".format(self.noise, 
       self.beak, self.wings)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `+` strings:

```
msg = "The bird is " + self.noise + " its beak is " + self.beak + " its wings are " + self.wings
```

Comment: Oh.. I thought I tried that but thanks it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)
```

tells you everything.

```
        msg = "The bird is ", self.noise "its beak is ", self.beak "its wings are ", self.wings
```

Separation with commas as in the above creates a tuple `(item1 , item2 , ...)`.

What you want is string concatenation with `+` or string formatting as shown in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use it `+` to concatenate the string:

```
 msg = "The bird is " + self.noise + "its beak is " + self.beak + "its wings are " + self.wings
```

so it would look like this:

```
class Bird:
    def __init__(self):
        self.noise = "chirping"
        self.beak = "closed"
        self.wings = "closed"
    def __str__(self):
        msg = "The bird is " + self.noise + "its beak is " + self.beak + "its wings are " + self.wings
        return msg
mybird = Bird()
print(mybird)
```

Output:

```
The bird is chirpingits beak is closedits wings are closed
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `msg` is not a `str` (string), but a tuple. Indeed:

```
msg = "The bird is ", self.noise "its beak is ", self.beak "its wings are ", self.wings
```

is a comma separated list of expressions and Python interprets this as:

```
msg = ("The bird is ", self.noise "its beak is ", self.beak "its wings are ", self.wings)
```

What you probably want is to append the parts which you can do using the plus (`+`) operator:

```
msg = "The bird is "+self.noise+" its beak is "+self.beak+" its wings are "+self.wings
```

Or you could use [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/):

```
msg = "The bird is %s its beak is %s its wings are "%(self.noise,self.beak,self.wings)
```

Comment: Or, alternatively `msg = "The bird is {} its beak is {} its wings are {}".format(self.noise, self.beak, self.wings)`

Comment: @Shiva: Yeah. I provided a link to a website dedicate to Python string formatting such that the OP can read more about it and decide how to format the string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return string from `__str__` fucntion:

```
noise = "chirping"
beak = "closed"
wings = "close"

msg = "The bird is ", noise, "its beak is ", beak, "its wings are ", wings
type(msg) # <class 'tuple'>
msg = "The bird is "+ noise+ "its beak is "+ beak+ "its wings are "+ wings
type(msg) # <class 'str'>
```